# How to calculate a 3D rect covers exact the full screen in Unity?

Tags: math, 3d, unity-game-engine

I have a Quad faces to the camera in a 3D scene, how can I calculate a position and size to make it covers the screen exactly in Unity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With those 4 vectors you should be able to build your quad. They are in a World space coords. The `10f` number is a distance from camera to the vertices.
You may also look at [this link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/599097/need-help-understanding-screentoworldpoint.html).

```
Vector3 p0 = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint( new Vector3(0, 0, 10f));
Vector3 p1 = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint( new Vector3(0, camera.pixelWidth, 10f));
Vector3 p2 = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint( new Vector3(camera.pixelHeight, camera.pixelWidth, 10f));
Vector3 p3 = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint( new Vector3(camera.pixelHeight, 0, 10f));
```